# Changing the width of the y-axis label area in jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqplot

Ok, I've got a bar chart.
And it basically works... but the labels on the y-axis are kinda long and wrap and then run into each other.

I've tried changing the css, but it gets overidden by JS. 
I tried scanning thru the jqplot library to find out where it happens but i got lost.
Any ideas? is there just an option i can set?

You can see here:

[image]

Here is my html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.jqplot.css" />
<script>
    $(function() {
        graph_me('chart1',[ 'This is a label', 'This is another label..', 'Is this too long? This looks like it might break','Im not sure, but '], [40, 20, 5, 1]);
    });
    function graph_me(div_name, labels_in, values_in) {
        var labels = labels_in.reverse();
        var values = values_in.reverse();
        $.jqplot(div_name, [values], {
            series:[{
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                rendererOptions: {
                    barDirection: 'horizontal',
                    varyBarColor: true
                    }
                }
            ],
            axes: {
                yaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer, 
                    ticks: labels,
                    tickOptions: {
                        showGridline: false,
                        markSize: 0
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart1" style="height:400px;width:500px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am having the sae problem icchanobot - did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @davy : the solution below worked for me, I think I just needed the `!important` part

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try this in your css:

```
.jqplot-yaxis {
  margin-left:-80px !important;
  width:80px !important;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I did figure it out using an answer very similar to this.